# Julia's @. macro and binary operators

Tags: julia

For all I know, the following should be equivalent:

```
julia> rand(2).^2
2-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.164246
 0.47107 

julia> @. rand(2)^2
ERROR: DimensionMismatch("Cannot multiply two vectors")
Stacktrace:
 [1] power_by_squaring(::Array{Float64,1}, ::Int64) at ./intfuncs.jl:169
 [2] broadcast(::##65#66) at ./sysimg.jl:86
```

Same goes for this one:

```
julia> 1./rand(2)
2-element Array{Float64,1}:
 1.93886
 3.01834

julia> @. 1/rand(2)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching /(::Int64, ::Array{Float64,1})
Closest candidates are:
  /(::PyCall.PyObject, ::Any) at /home/simon/.julia/v0.6/PyCall/src/pyoperators.jl:11
  /(::Union{Int128, Int16, Int32, Int64, Int8, UInt128, UInt16, UInt32, UInt64, UInt8}, ::Union{Int128, Int16, Int32, Int64, Int8, UInt128, UInt16, UInt32, UInt64, UInt8}) at int.jl:38
  /(::Union{Int16, Int32, Int64, Int8, UInt16, UInt32, UInt64, UInt8}, ::BigInt) at gmp.jl:381
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] broadcast(::##69#70) at ./sysimg.jl:86
```

What the heck am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not the answer, but note that `1./rand(2)` is ambiguous. It can mean `1. / rand(2)` or `1 ./ rand(2)`. First would throw error, second do what you want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> help?> @.
>
> @. expr
>
> Convert **every function call or operator** in expr into a *"dot call"*
>   (e.g. convert `f(x)` to `f.(x)`), and convert **every assignment** in expr to
>   a *"dot   assignment"* (e.g. convert `+=` to `.+=`).
>
> If you want to **avoid adding dots for selected function calls** in
>   expr, **splice those function calls in with `$`**.
>
> For example, `@. sqrt(abs($sort(x)))` is equivalent to `sqrt.(abs.(sort(x)))` (no dot for
>   sort).

The problem is that this way you are also broadcasting `rand`, the `@.` macro works on all function calls including binary operators calls (ie. `1 + 1` is parsed as `+(1, 1)`)

1. Use the `@macroexpand` macro in order to see the resulting expression from a macro invocation.
2. Interpolate the function calls (`$(f(x))`) that you don't want to broadcast with `@.`.

```rb
julia> @macroexpand @. rand(2)^2
:(^.(rand.(2), 2))    # same as: rand.(2).^2

julia> eval(ans)
ERROR: DimensionMismatch("Cannot multiply two vectors")

julia> @macroexpand @. $(rand(2))^2
:(^.(rand(2), 2))  # same as: rand(2).^2

julia> eval(ans)
2-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.26266
 0.326033

julia> @macroexpand @. 1 / rand(2)
:(/.(1, rand.(2)))    # same as: 1 ./ rand.(2)

julia> eval(ans)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching /(::Int64, ::Array{Float64,1})

julia> @macroexpand @. 1 / $(rand(2))
:(/.(1, rand(2)))    # same as: 1 ./ rand(2)

julia> eval(ans)
2-element Array{Float64,1}:
 37.1023
  1.08004
```

Comment: An excellent explanations. I think it is worth to add that the problem is that e.g. `exp.(rand.(2))` fails because it is equivalent to `broadcast(x->exp(rand(x)), 2)`, and in this representation it is clear that this code will throw an error.